# Combination of more than one condition with TYPOSCRIPT

Tags: conditional-statements, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I have a problem switching combined conditions from TYPO3 9 LTS to TYPO3 10 LTS.

The syntax so far looks like this:

```
[PIDinRootline = 31] && [treeLevel = 4]
    page.10.variables.cagmenu < lib.cagpagebrowser
[global]
```

I adapted the new syntax as follows:

```
[31 in tree.rootLineIds] && [tree.level == 5]
    page.10.variables.cagmenu < lib.cagpagebrowser
[global]
```

If I omit the second condition `&& [tree.level ==4]` the desired behaviour is implemented on all subpages of the page with ID=31.

How do I have to implement my condition accordingly so that it also works under TYPO3 10 LTS?

Answer (score 10):

The logical operater has to be used inside the square brackets.

so your condition would be:
`[31 in tree.rootLineIds && tree.level == 5]` or
`[31 in tree.rootLineIds and tree.level == 5]`

More information can be found in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/Configuration/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html#combining-conditions)

Comment: Maybe you can update your correct answer with a hint to the syntax before v10 (and Symfony Expression Language) like the "Note" block in the manual: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/Configuration/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html#combining-conditions

Comment: I specified the target in the link. I think the old syntax is not necessary in my answer as it was shown in the question and in the linked manual.